# Using jQuery to target (this) not working as expected

Tags: jquery, html, css, hover

I'm trying my hands on some jQuery and there is some part I don't understand. It's also hard for me to google because I'm not quite sure of the terminology - hence why I am asking the question and will explain my exact intentions.

Here is my HTML markup.

```
<div class="contentLarge">

<a href=""><header>Use responsive design.</header></a>

<div class="contentFlex">
    <div class="contentFlex1"></div>
    <div class="contentFlex2"></div>
</div>
```

Now what I want is that when I hover over the anchor link, the background of the entire contentLarge container changes. I have several of these containers on my page.

Here is the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".contentLarge header").mouseenter(function(){
        $(".contentLarge").css({"background-color": "red"})
    });
});
```

Now I understand that now when I hover  - each contentLarge container will get it's background changed to red. This is not what I want.

But when I try using the $(this) selector for targetting within this function - it's the HEADER that gets changed, not the contentLarge. Like so;

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".contentLarge header").mouseenter(function(){
        $("this").css({"background-color": "red"})
    });
});
```

How do I write it so that $(this) is the target container - changing only it's background to red instead of either all containers, or only the header.

Comment: Try $(this).closest('.contentLarge').css({"background-color": "red"}) to target the closest contentLarge div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `parent()` to point at the `.contentLarge` container that holds the link you hover over:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".contentLarge header").mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).parent().css({"background-color": "red"})
    });
});
```

Another options would be to use `closest()`, which searches for the closest intance with the `.contentLarge` class. Useful to prevent using `.parent().parent().parent()...` when there are multiple layers between your `.header` and the `.contentClass`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".header").mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).closest('.contentLarge').css({"background-color": "red"})
    });
});
```